# Why doesn't FullSimplify work properly on this?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, factorization

I wish to simplify the simple expression `fac[n_] := Sum[R^i, {i, 0, n}];` as much as possible for various $n$. `FullSimplify` or `Factor` work on this, but not always, as good as it should be. For example, in the sixth line of

```
Table[{fac[j], fac[j] // FullSimplify, fac[j] // Factor}, {j, 1, 8}] // TableForm
```

it seems that `FullSimplify` does not work at all!?

[image]

$1+R+R^2+R^3+R^4+R^5+R^6$ has not been simplified! It is well-known that $$1+R+R^2+R^3+R^4+R^5+R^6=1+(R+R^4)(1+R+R^2).$$

So, now my question is: Is there any way in *Mathematica* to obtain the very simplified form of the expression `fac[n_] := Sum[R^i, {i, 0, n}];`, just like $1+(R+R^4)(1+R+R^2)$ or even simpler for various $n$?

I will be grateful if anyone can give me some tips.

Comment: Why not just `Sum[R^i, {i, 0, n}]`?

Comment: Note that $1+R+R^2+R^3+R^4+R^5+R^6$ requires 5 multiplications to be implemented, while $1+(R+R^4)(1+R+R^2)$ requires only 3! That is why a more factorized form is desirable.

Comment: Please execute the command I wrote above

Comment: "More factorized" and "fewer multiplications" are not the same as "simple".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to write your own `ComplexityFunction` for the task. For instance, this function produces different results from default:

```
FullSimplify[Sum[R^i, {i, 0, 6}], 
 ComplexityFunction -> (2 Count[#, Plus, Infinity, Heads -> True] + 
     Total@Cases[#, _^n_ :> n, Infinity] &)]
```

> 1 + R (1 + R) (1 - R + R^2) (1 + R + R^2)

It's not what you were looking for, though. You can try to change `ComplexityFunction` and look at what kind of search space `FullSimplify` looks through with something like this, which sows all expressions passed to `ComplexityFunction`:

```
Reap[FullSimplify[Sum[R^i, {i, 0, 6}], 
   ComplexityFunction -> ((Sow[#]; LeafCount[#]) &)]] // Last
```

Results are not particularly promising in this case, though; it would seem `FullSimplify` doesn't visit a single time those alternatives you wanted to see. I'm not certain of it, but the complexity function in use might also affect the direction simplification tries to pursue. (By the way, transformations in use can be augmented through `TransformationFunctions`.)

Completely different route for this kinds of optimizations is to look on answers related to `Compile`. Some effort to exactly the direction you were interested of (minimizing amount of multiplications) has been pursued by others on Mma.SE.